# Storing Special Character in Oracle and with .net Application

Tags: .net, oracle11g

I am developing a .net windows application with oracle database. Our requirement is to replace "&#188" with ¼ (ascii 188) on UI and save in oracle table.  But after replacing the value it is showing "reversed" question mark on UI and in the oracle table it storing as question mark when i am quering the table using pl/sql developer.

Can some some has dealt with this type of problem?

Thanks,
H N MIshra

Answer (score 0):

ASCII runs from 0 to 127. There is no ASCII character 188. There is a Unicode character `U+00BC` = ¼, and 00BC hex indeed is 188 decimal. That's the hint for the answer: use Unicode, then it's easy. Luckily .Net already uses Unicode, and in Oracle it's just a simple setting.

Comment: There are more than 350 html charcaters to be replace with some other value and we are keeping all those in Oracle table to replace those on fly. When i copied those value from note pad to oracle table,  ¼ converted intto "?". Whereas on some developred machines .net interface is showing correct value i.e. ¼ after replacement however their pl/sql developer also showing "?" in table. But on my machine both .net interface and pl/sql developer showing "?". Is there any setting in Window to show correct value for these special characters?

Comment: @H.N.Mishra: Don't use Notepad for checking special characters. Your problems are probably caused by Notepad.

Comment: @Codo: Notepad has no problems whatsoever. It's fully Unicode, like all Windows components. It therefore doesn't even have the notion of "special" characters. `U+00BC` is just a character like `U+007C` or `U+8BFE`. Oracle, on the other hand, uses multiple different character encodings such as Latin-1.

Comment: @MSalters: You are probably right. The problem is less with Notepad and more with text files using a single byte encoding. But regarding Oracle: I've never seen an encoding problem with any Oracle component. While it does use different encoding, it is fully aware of it and always correctly converts text or throws an error when it cannot losslessly store a test due to a restricted character set.

Comment: I added a key NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252 in \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\KEY_OraClient11g_home2 (having two ora home and home2 is default one) on my PC and now woking fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Oracle database is setup with a character set that does not include the ¼ character. (I'm assuming that you mean Unicode code point 188 as the ASCII character set doesn't include ¼ either.)

Most likely, you'll need to convert the character set of your database. I recommend AL32UTF8 (UTF-8), which supports the full Unicode range.

There's an Oracle document that describtes the [character set migration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm).

Comment: Charcater set with Oracle DB is fine becuase it is showing correctly on other developers machine. I believe it some local setting for the client machines which needs to change to show up this correctly?

Comment: @H.N.Mishra: If this is the case, then I don't think your problem is with Oracle or the .NET code for accessing the database (ADO.NET probably). Because they basically use Unicode, are fully aware of the character set and don't introduce problems. Please describe the full pipeline of all tools from the database to the UI. Any step in the pipeline might have changed to ¼ character.